# way to save Json response in to array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i want to save each json response in an array i did write like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var saveJson = [];
   var jsonResponse = getjsonResponse()
                      //something with $get function response json format 
   saveJson = saveToArray(jsonResponse.SearchResults);

   var saveToArray = function(array){
       $.each(array,function(i,data){
           saveJson.push(data);
       });
   };
});
```

but seems to be my code does not work saveJson getting undefined how can i overcome this? simply i want to append json response to one array object.

my sample response look like

```
    "SearchResults":[
          {
             "TypeFlag":"W",
             "HashCode":"66093013",
             "ShortenKey":"http:///k",
             "Title":"Yahoo! \u003cspan class=\"search-result-highlight\"\u003eSearch\u003c/span\u003e - Web \u003cspan class=\"search-result-highlight\"\u003eSearch\u003c/span\u003e",
             "Description":"The \u003cb\u003esearch\u003c/b\u003e engine that helps you find exactly what you\u0027re looking for. Find the most relevant information, video, images, and answers from all across the Web.",
             "Url":"http://search.yahoo.com/",
             "LastUpdateOn":"6/21/2011 1:01:11 PM",
             "PageRank":1,
             "ThumbImageUrl":""
          },
         {
             "TypeFlag":"W",
             "HashCode":"48394089",
             "ShortenKey":"http:///5i",
             "Title":"Lijit | Advertising Services, Audience Analytics and Publisher ...",   
             "Description":"I’ve been using Lijit as my site \u003cb\u003esearch\u003c/b\u003e for several years and the understanding I get about my audience is critical to knowing what my readership is interested in and ...",
             "Url":"http://www.lijit.com/",
             "LastUpdateOn":"6/22/2011 11:31:41 PM",
             "PageRank":10,
             "ThumbImageUrl":""
      }
]
```

thanks

Comment: Your code does not really make sense. You assign a function `jsonResponse` and then pass it to `saveToArray`, treating the function as array. If you are actually calling the a function to get the response, I assume you make an Ajax request. Ajax is **asynchronous**. You have to use a callback that handles the response. I suggest you have a look at some Ajax examples.

Comment: OK i'll edit with my json sample object

Comment: What does `getjsonResponse` do? If ithas an async request, you need a callback function to process it. (not just assume it's loaded on the next line)

Comment: @digitalFresh it's jquery $get function getting json format response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function(array){
    $.each(array,function(i,data){
        saveJson.push(data);
    });
};
```

returns *undefined*. Although you push data into saveJson, your "saveJson = saveToArray(jsonResponse)" re-assign the saveJson as *undefined*.

You might have :

```
function(array){
    var ret = [];
    $.each(array,function(i,data){
        ret.push(data);
    });
    return ret;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is not an array, you actually have an object containing an array in "SearchResults", so you have to pass that on instead of the entire object:

```
saveJson = saveToArray(jsonResponse.SeachResults); //change this line
```

(assuming `jsonResponse` is defined)