# How to save parseJSON responses to an array

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, post, each

I want to use `$.post` method for sending and receiving database tables, and I want to save responses to an array that I defined, but it doesn't save it outside of function. How to fix that?

```
var source = [];
$(function()
{
  $.post("PostPath.php",
        function(response){ 
        var data = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
        $.each(data, function( key, value) {
            source.push(value);
            alert(source); // here source array has values
        })
    }) 
 })

alert(source); // but here source array is undefined
```

Comment: can you please just check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477802/way-to-save-json-response-in-to-array i hope this will help you to find some soluation from that.

Comment: You have to understand that $.post is an asynchronized call. You second alert(source) is executed before $.post. If you try alert(1), alert(2) in those places you can see the order of execution.

Answer (score 0):

You push in path, not in source :

```
var source = [];
$(function
{
  $.post("PostPath.php",
        function(response){ 
        $.each(response, function( key, value) {
            source.push(value);
        })
        console.log(source);
    }, 'json') 
})
```

Comment: sorry i had mistake for write code in stackoverflow, yes it's source but haven't value outside of function

Comment: So look to your response content. Do you have something returned ?

Comment: yes absolutely it have, and as i said alert(source); in function have value but outside it haven't any value;